# Store C++ classes in JNI context

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have two C++ classes, one for creating a factory and another of the type of object which this factory creates.

*Code Snippet*:

```
class A{

};

class Factory
{
    public:
        A *CreateObject(char *p);
};

Factory *CreateFactory(char *);
```

So, I want the similar classes on Java side, for `Factory` and concrete class `A`. But, I am not able to understand that, when I call the `CreateFactory` function through `JNI`, where should I store the `Factory` instance which it returns?

Please help!

Comment: Most of the time when you're using JNI you want the class representation to only exist in Java. JNI allows you to create native methods, which can access the Java Object that they're part of (if they're not static). If it is really necessary that you have c++ class instance you might want to store it as a long (bad practice) or, if you know the size, store it as a DirectByteBuffer (also bad practice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can associate native objects with Java objects by creating a `private long` field in the Java class and store the pointer to the native object in that field via JNI.

Comment: @Mast3rPlan: as native code is always. But that’s the way the JRE classes itself do it. Notice the `private` modifier for the field. If you can’t avoid using native code there aren’t much alternatives.

Comment: I would say using a private long field is definitely the easiest way to go, although I still strongly suggest using the java class itself to store any data when possible.

Comment: @Mast3rPlan: Agreed. I recommend avoiding native code as much as possible. So usually the stored pointers are OS resources and not C++ objects in real life code.

Comment: Exactly, I completely agree, I guess using JNI is something that you want to avoid. If anything go with [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) which has nearly no performance loss (unless unsafe JNI is enabled).

Comment: Thank you for suggesting JNA